# Re-keying a dictionary

Tags: python, random, dictionary

So I have a Python assignment where I need to use a dictionary to hold the items of a menu, then randomly re-key and re-order the menu so that I can change the order of the menu options printed out. Here is an example of the code I have:

```
ChoiceOne = "Rekey Menu"
ChoiceTwo = "Quit"
menu = {'1':ChoiceOne, '2':ChoiceTwo,}
userChoice = input("Please Enter the Integer for Your Menu Choice: ")

while userChoice not in menu.keys():
    print("Invalid Input")
    userChoice = input("Please Enter the Integer for Your Menu Choice: ")

if menu[userChoice] == ChoiceOne:
    menu = rekey(menu)
elif menu[userChoice] == ChoiceTwo:
    quit()
```

The above code loops while the user chooses not to quit, repeatedly printing out the menu over and over again. The following is my rekey() function

```
def rekey(menu):
    rekey = {}
    keylist = random.sample(range(10), 2)
    for i, item in zip(keylist, menu ):
        rekey[i] = menu[item]
    return rekey
```

My problem seems to present itself in the line where I check whether the user input for the menu option is valid or not. Initially, entering anything other than "1" or "2" will cause the program to enter the While loop until a valid input is entered. After rekeying the menu however, the line "while userChoice not in menu.keys()" is always triggered and no input is ever matched to continue the program.

I've tried to find the problem by printing out the new keys in the dictionary and checking to see if the userChoice matches any one of them, but even when I choose a valid new key, the program seems to think that nothing I enter is a valid key.

I hope I've described the problem well enough to be understood, thanks for the help in advance!!

Comment: Disregard my answer. I thought about it for a second and realized that it was completely wrong. Plz vote 2 delete.

Comment: Are the checks for `menu[userChoice]` supposed to be inside the while loop (i.e. this got messed up during posting) or outside? If the latter, then I see no outer loop to prompt again after re-keying...

Comment: You can build the dictionary in `rekey()` much more simply: `return dict(zip(random.sample(range(10), 2), menu))`. Or rather, fixing the problem: `return dict(zip(map(str, random.sample(range(10), 2)), menu))`. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first case the menu keys are *strings*, after the rekey they are *ints*. You need to do a conversion of either the keys or the user input so they match.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The problem was solved when I changed "rekey[i] = menu[item]" to "rekey[str(i)] = menu[item]"

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input) the `input(x)` function is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(x))`. This means that typing "1" at the input prompt is equivalent to typing "1" in the python interpreter, so you get the *integer* 1.

As SpliFF has already pointed out, you need to ensure that you're either using integer keys in your menu dictionary, or you could use string keys for the dictionary and switch to using the `raw_input` function to read the user's choice.

Comment: Note: `input()` and `raw_input()` behave this way in Python 2. The OP's use of `print` as a function `print()` suggests he *may* be using Python 3.

Comment: Hmm, yes I think you're probably right. Note also the use of `range` instead of `xrange` which also suggests that Python 3 is being used.

Comment: This is definitely Py3, or `rekey` would never be called, since the initial dict keys are strings.

Comment: Astute and accurate observations all around. It's fun to see that everybody on here is passionate enough about these topics to read so much into the code.